# Is there a subscription feature to notify me of new questions in tag?

Tags: feature-request, support, subscription

I found that it is hard to read all posts who have the tag I subscribed for. I think there is a feature that I that allows me to receive notifications from the feed for all tags I want to know about.

Can anyone explain how it's possible or can I request this feature?

Answer (score 6):

Just hover with your mouse over the tag and click "subscribe":

[image]

Comment: RSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: -1 See my separate non-answer.

Answer (score -1):

(I meant to write this as a comment to @Sha Wiz Dow Ard but it got too long.  TLDR version: "me too".  This is a clarification of what I think the question amounts to, not an attempt to answer it.)

I have a few tag subscriptions but I find the email interface quite ungainly; I receive a notification only nightly, when everything else on SO is basically instantaneous; and very frequently, by the time I actually read my email, I have already read (and perhaps even answered) the question that the email highlights.

What I'd like to see (too?) is a little colored blot in the upper left corner of the SE web page when there's a new question in a tag I'm subscribed to.

Ideally, the email should be completely unnecessary, and the subscription integrated to the site's general user interface.  If that cannot happen, at least it would be useful if there was an option to only receive email when I have not already read the question.

Comment: Well, as Will said there is also RSS feed, this should be more instant as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Okay for "workaround exists" but I find it severely ... puzzling that the subscription option is not at all as well integrated into the site as the other tracking features.

Comment: Not my downvote - I don't really disagree with what you say just think it's not worth doing it with the existing alternative which is RSS feeds. Sorry if wasn't clear enough.