# How can I browse custom tag filters created by other users?

Tags: support, tags, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I am a heavy user of custom tag filters through stackexchange.com.  For all of my custom filters, I am (unsurprisingly) the only follower.  However, custom filters are public, and I can browse/view/follow filters created by others by manually constructing a relevant URI and guessing a filter ID:

- https://stackexchange.com/filters/100
- https://stackexchange.com/filters/1000
- https://stackexchange.com/filters/10000

etc...  but that's not a very efficient way of searching.

Are there any other ways of browsing custom tag filters, apart from manually constructing an URI? How can I find what custom stackexchange.com tag filters are popular?

Comment: You can't browse. Do note, that most followers we see now have subscribed via the old tag popup.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard The linked question doesn't address how I /find/ other tag filters.  What is the tag popup?  So the answer then is: there is no mechanism to find other filters, if not given a direct link?

Comment: Yes it's a case of "This is not possible, so the most similar request can be the next best thing", which I use as dupe. If you want I can reopen. Tag popup is the window that appears when hovering over a tag, instead of "Watch Tag" there used to be "subscribe" link (you can see how it looked like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86845/152859)) which created actual filter for that tag, if didn't exist already, and added the user as Follower. Now I'm pretty sure it's different, and no such auto filters exist anymore. (Well, not created or updated at least.)